# Mutex could not be created. ASP.NET

Tags: c#, asp.net

I have got problem with creation Mutex. I don't know why because server is using new NET Framework. Can you help me?

Version Information: Microsoft .NET Framework Version:4.0.30319; ASP.NET Version:4.0.30319.272

There is my website and this error:
http://www.rafaljaworowski.somee.com/

Description: An unhandled exception occurred during the execution of the current web request. Please review the stack trace for more information about the error and where it originated in the code.

Exception Details: System.InvalidOperationException: Mutex could not be create

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this...

Happened me years ago and the information in this article helped.

It was related to running ASP.NET process under a non standard account.

http://blogs.msdn.com/b/jorman/archive/2006/07/24/676660.aspx

Comment: Hmm I have question to this link which you sent to me. You know in my computer I haven`t got this problem but only in hosting when I send my website. If I will do this in my computer is it possible to rapair this problem in hosting? There show only how Close Handle but all processes are only in my computer but probem is in hosting.

Comment: no this is an issue with the IIS/ASP.NET Setup in your hosting environment. If you don't control your hosting environment then you'll need to call their tech support and ask them to apply those fixes.

Answer (score 1):

While searching for this issue I came accross with this. This worked for me.

1. With a command window, get to the latest version of .net under
   C:\Windows\Microsoft.Net\Framework\
2. Now run the following command: "net stop w3svc" to stop web services.
3. Then use "aspnet_regiis.exe -ua" to uninstall all instances of ASP.NET from IIS.
4. Follow with "aspnet_regiis.exe -i" to install ASP.NET into IIS.
5. Now restart web services with "net start w3svc".